# Bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data:
[image]

I want to have a bar chart where for each group I have two bars (IT and PT) side by side: this is my script:

```
 ggplot(score, aes(group, IT, fill = stain)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill")+  
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
    ggplot(score, aes(group, PT, fill = stain)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#edae49", "#d1495b", "#00798c", "#30638e"))+
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
     ggtitle("CD4")
```

how can I put the PT and IT on the same y-axis?
Also, how can I keep 0% values on the plot without having the auto NA instead?

I need something like that:

```
score$group <- factor(score$group, levels=c("All_BrM", "Sync","Meta","Poly" ))
  score$stain <- factor(score$stain, levels=c("none", "<10%","10-40%",">40%" ))
  
  ggplot(score, aes(group, IT, fill = stain)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill")+  
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ded9e2", "#c0b9dd", "#80a1d4", "#75c9c8"))+
    theme_prism(base_size = 9)+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 10, angle=50))+
  ggplot(score, aes(group, PT, fill = stain)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ded9e2", "#c0b9dd", "#80a1d4", "#75c9c8"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())  +            
    theme_prism(base_size = 9)+
    theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 10, angle=50))
```

Comment: Please don't include pictures of data. Pictures of data cannot be copy / pasted into the console to replicate the data set. Try pasting the output of `dput(score)` into your question to produce a replicable data set.

Comment: ´´´                                                                                                       
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("All_BrM", "Sync", "Meta", "Poly"), class = "factor"), 
    stain = c("< 10%", ">10%", "< 10%", ">10%", "< 10%", ">10%", 
    "< 10%", ">10%"), IT = c(55, 1, 15, 1, 18, 0, 22, 0), PT = c(40, 
    6, 10, 1, 15, 2, 15, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")                       
 ´´´

Answer (score 0):

It will make life easier if you start by pivoting your data into long format. That is, instead of having one column for IT and one for PT, you have a single column with all the values, and another column labeling the value in that row as coming from either PT or IT. You can do this easily with `pivot_longer`.

It sounds like you want to stack the bars according to group, but have them dodged according to IT / PT. You can't both stack and dodge directly, but you can fake it with facets:

Your code might then look something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

score %>%
  pivot_longer(IT:PT, names_to = 'IT_PT') %>%
  mutate(stain = factor(stain, unique(stain)),
         group = factor(group, unique(group))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(IT_PT, value, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  facet_grid(.~stain, switch = 'x') +
  scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values =  c("#edae49", "#d1495b", 
                                             "#00798c", "#30638e")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('', ''), name = 'Stain', 
                   expand = c(0.1, 0.7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, I don't have your data, so I had to transcribe it manually from the picture in your question.

```r
score <- structure(list(group = c("All_BrM", "All_BrM", "All_BrM", "All_BrM", 
"Sync", "Sync", "Sync", "Sync", "Meta", "Meta", "Meta", "Meta", 
"Poly", "Poly", "Poly", "Poly"), stain = c("0%", "<10%", "11-40%", 
">40%", "0%", "<10%", "11-40%", ">40%", "0%", "<10%", "11-40%", 
">40%", "0%", "<10%", "11-40%", ">40%"), IT = c(20, 35, 1, 0, 
2, 13, 1, 0, 9, 9, 0, 0, 9, 13, 0, 0), PT = c(9, 30, 6, 0, 1, 
9, 1, 0, 4, 10, 2, 0, 4, 11, 3, 0)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Thank you Allan for your help, but I also need to have all the percentages for every group in one column out of 100%

Comment: @Mimi see my update - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mimi the code above works perfectly with the data above, which was taken from your quesiton.

Comment: thank you but should be different, the best thing I could do is the following: please see the script in the answer below, I also want to calculate p-values among Sync, meta and poly to see which have more positive staining (the data I sent before above), I have there the counts of how many samples had the mentioned percentage of each group (IT and PT) are different regions of the tissue, which test would you recommend and how can I ass the p-values above the charts?

Answer (score 0):

@Allan Cameron

```
score$group <- factor(score$group, levels=c("All_BrM", "Sync","Meta","Poly" ))
  score$stain <- factor(score$stain, levels=c("none", "<10%","10-40%",">40%" ))
  
  ggplot(score, aes(group, IT, fill = stain)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill")+  
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ded9e2", "#c0b9dd", "#80a1d4", "#75c9c8"))+
    theme_prism(base_size = 9)+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 10, angle=50))+
  ggplot(score, aes(group, PT, fill = stain)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ded9e2", "#c0b9dd", "#80a1d4", "#75c9c8"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())  +            
    theme_prism(base_size = 9)+
    theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 10, angle=50))
```